# With how many ways can there be $n$ couplings between $n$ men and $n$ women?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Could you help me with the following exercise? Could you give me a hint?

> With how many ways can there be $n$ couplings between $n$ men and $n$ women?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a woman(ladies first)... how many men has she to choose from? Then with another woman... $$n(n-1)...$$

Comment: Aha! So is then the answer $n!$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Well Done.

Comment: Ok!!! Thank you Awesome!!!

Comment: It feels so good to hear that...